# Validate an iSCSI target

Tags: c++, linux, unix, redhat

Is there any way to validate an iSCSI target's iqn. For example, we use ping x.x.x.x to check if we can connect to a remote machine.

I am parsing the output of 'iscsiadm -m session' command's output to get the remote machine's IP and the corresponding target LUN's iqn. I can check the correctness of the IP by trying to ping it. I am not sure how to validate an iqn. The command output may change depending on iscsiadm's version installed. Therefore, I want to validate if what I parsed was right before using the IP and iqn for other operations.

Sample output of the command:
 iscsiadm -m session
tcp: [1] 172.19.99.116:3260,1 iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:0-8a0906-79728210b-913004cb4a755c4d-smagentlynx02-sk-5g-sk (non-flash)

Comment: If you already have an established session to the target, it would seem to me that that is sufficient validation that the iqn is correct - if it weren't, you would not have been able to establish that session. Unless you're concerned that the target may no longer be responding - but that's a bit different question...

Comment: in my program I am running the iscsi adm command (iscsiadm -m session) and then parsing the output of that command. So the application actually does not know if the parsed string which is the iqn is correct or not.